# How to get a specific value from Json string without deserialising the entire string into classes

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

I am fairly new to Json parsing. From my Json (see below) I would like to  extract the 'id' (present in data section) value at the moment.

```
{
    "data": [{
            "date": "2018-10-10 10:50:00",
            "vehicle_id": 11,
            "accept_phone": true,
            "phone": "070000000",
            "accept_email": true,
            "email": "abe@abeprakash.com",
            "details": "Special Very",
            "user_id": "3378",
            "id": 11513,
            "team_id": 2806,
            
            "user_info": {
                "id": 3378,
                "name_first": "abe",
                "name_last": "prakash",
                "name_full": "abe prakash ",
                "email": "abe@abeprakash.com",
                "phone": "070000000",
                "ratings_count": 0
            },
    
                "recipient": {
                    "name": "Tim ",
                    "email": "Dev@journease.co.uk",
                    "phone": "+44 (0)117 9586 180"
                },
                "footer_text": "",
                "invoice_logo": "",
                "including_vat": 0
            },
            "distance_in_miles": 0,
            "vehicle": {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Abe Car",
                "icon": "\/assets\/uploads\/vehicles\/11.svg",
                "sort_no": 8,
                "size": 800
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties": []
}
```

I have been experimenting and this is how far i have gotten, not sure if this is the best way to do it either

**Try 1** (topLevelResponse  is nothing but id in json string has a value)

```
Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                    'Use the below variable to see the rawJson
                    Dim rawJsonResponseString = ""
                    Using rawJsonResponseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(rawJsonResponseStream, Encoding.UTF8)
                        rawJsonResponseString = reader.ReadToEnd()
                    End Using
Dim topLevelResponse As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawJsonResponseString)("data").SelectToken("id")
```

**Try 2** (i don't want to loop through to find id as there might be loads more items in the json response in future)

```
Dim token As JToken = CType(topLevelResponse.SelectToken("data"), JArray)
```

Any help is much appreciated guys. As you guys might have spotted, I am using VB.net and Json.net. Thank you.

**Try 3** (I got the value but now sure its a good idea to hardcode where the value, there will always be one position in the data though)

Dim extractedID = JObject.Parse(rawJsonResponseString).SelectToken("data[0].id")

Comment: That's not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a valid JSON:

> {"data":[{"date":"2018-10-1010:50:00","vehicle_id":11,"accept_phone":true,"phone":"070000000","accept_email":true,"email":"abe@abeprakash.com","details":"SpecialVery","user_id":"3378","id":11513,"team_id":2806,"user_info":{"id":3378,"name_first":"abe","name_last":"prakash","name_full":"abeprakash","email":"abe@abeprakash.com","phone":"070000000","ratings_count":0},"recipient":{"name":"Tim","email":"Dev@journease.co.uk","phone":"+44(0)1179586180"},"footer_text":"","invoice_logo":"","including_vat":0,"distance_in_miles":0,"vehicle":{"id":11,"name":"AbeCar","icon":"/assets/uploads/vehicles/11.svg","sort_no":8,"size":800}}],"properties":[]}

Since it was not valid, I don't know how you didn't get an error upon attempting to parse it, or maybe you just posted it wrong here.

Back on topic, There are multiple ways but here is the shortest as you asked.

**Visualized steps:**

```
{JSON}
```

---

```
{
  "data":[+], '<<< ("data")
  "properties":[+]
}
```

---

```
{
  "data":[
    {+} '<<< first, that is (0)
  ],
  "properties":[+]
}
```

---

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "date":"2018-10-1010:50:00",
      "vehicle_id":11,
      "accept_phone":true,
      "phone":"070000000",
      "accept_email":true,
      "email":"abe@abeprakash.com",
      "details":"SpecialVery",
      "user_id":"3378",
      "id":11513, '<<< ("id")
      "team_id":2806,
      "user_info":{+},
      "recipient":{+},
      "footer_text":"",
      "invoice_logo":"",
      "including_vat":0,
      "distance_in_miles":0,
      "vehicle":{+}
    }
  ],
  "properties":[+]
}
```

---

```
Dim test As JObject = JObject.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
Dim test1 = test("data")(0)("id") 'test1 = 11513
```

You should inspect the JObject with breakpoint and look at how format looks to know how can you get what you want. Arrays by numbers, rest by name (or key if you will).

Comment: Or you could use something to visualize it easier while validating at the same time, like this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: thanks for the comment but i can simply use notepad++ for this.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation defo deserves a upvote, your answer is almost the same as my 'Try 3'.

Comment: The format will remain the same, what could change is number of items in the array. So you could make data > for each loop > id

Comment: So, what exactly was the question xD, once you do JObject.Parse it's done. Getting what you want takes a fraction of a second.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing my Try 3. i.e., not hardcoding the text id. But if the API Response changes the code will change anyway. Thanks for looking into this. Appreciate it xD

Comment: It shouldn't change, how would app communicate with it if it would wildly change format? It' has to have a consistent structure in order to work. Your alternative is to loop over all keys and then work with what you have.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i have found so far and as per comments from stack members is below

Dim extractedID = JObject.Parse(rawJsonResponseString).SelectToken("data[0].id")